# Stage is not cleared between animation frames

Tags: html5-canvas, createjs, easeljs

Canvas get all frames layered over and over without clearing the stage when there is no background image set and some SpriteSheet animation is playing.

How to avoid that and clear the Stage on each frame of that animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The EaselJS stage should clear each time it is updated (using `stage.update()`) before it redraws, *unless* you have `stage.autoClear=false;`.

If that is not working, then something else is going on. Any chance you can post code or a working sample?

Comment: Thank you Lanny for that great support! That was autoClear flag (set it long ago and didn't notice it's still there..)

Answer (score 0):

Stage.removeAllChildren() which will remove all the children in the stage.

Here is the link

http://createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html#method_removeAllChildren